# Accessing the child node in XML using SAXParser in android

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I have the following structure of my XML tree:

```
<building id="5" name="Barracks" hp="2000" >
    <cost metal="100" wood = "300"></cost>
    <unit id="1" name="Swordsman" hp="40" attack="3"/>
    <tech id="1" name="Research Heavy Swordsman"/>
</building>
```

Here's my code that I use to access it:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            int civId=0, id=0;
            if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("building"))
            {
                inBuilding = true;
                building = true;
                //Fetching the ID of TownCenter, we use it as a reference to fetch the child nodes.
                id = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("id"));
                if(id==5)
                {
                    XMLfetch.put("id", attributes.getValue("id"));
                    XMLfetch.put("name", attributes.getValue("name"));
                    XMLfetch.put("hp", attributes.getValue("hp"));
                    ......
                }               
            }
            if(inBuilding && id==5){ //<----- Condition which matters
                if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost")){

                    Log.i("resources", "Wood "+attributes.getValue("wood"));
                    Log.i("resources", "MetaL "+attributes.getValue("metal"));

                    XMLfetch.put("costWood", attributes.getValue("wood"));
                    XMLfetch.put("costMetal", attributes.getValue("stone"));

                }               
            }
        }

        // END ELEMENT here     
                @Override
                 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

                    if(inBuilding)
                    {
                        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("building")) {
                              building=false;
                              //inBuilding=false;
                              }
                        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost")){
                            inBuilding=false;
                        }
                    }

                 }
```

Now the problem is, I cannot get inside the  tag. I cannot access its attributes, nothing. If I remove the condition of "id==5" from the line that I have mentioned, the code fetches all the values of cost from the entire tree. But, when I put the condition, it fetches nothing! :( ...

Please help. THanks a lot!

Comment: Your XML file you posted is missing a quote by name=Barracks. Can you post what attributes.getValue("id") is and what id is right before the if(id==5) call?

Comment: It is solved!
I had declared the inBuilding variable at a wrong place. :( ....
Thus, the variables got rewritten and I couldn't detect where I was.
Thanks though for all the people who read it and tried to give a solution. :)
The civId and id variables are declared inside startElement(), that means they get re-written everytime.... thus they are useless. They need to be declared anywhere they won't be re-written.
Thanks ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

It is solved! I had declared the inBuilding variable at a wrong place. :( .... Thus, the variables got rewritten and I couldn't detect where I was. Thanks though for all the people who read it and tried to give a solution. :) The civId and id variables are declared inside startElement(), that means they get re-written everytime.... thus they are useless. They need to be declared anywhere they won't be re-written. Thanks ianhanniballake